# Use both Subversion and Git in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, svn

Idea for workflow:
Use Git locally and do x commits / branches.
Once a complete feature is done, do a single commit to the SVN server.

Is this possible in Visual Studio without remapping the source control bindings all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just kept using the Visual Studio plugin for the team source control and used git on the command line for more granularity.

Works pretty good.